# Touch Cancel IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have an IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Called");
    if (timer) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

This should stop the timer that is running, I've included the `NSLog` to to see if my invalidating of the timer is bad or if the method isn't even being called, and, it's not being called. I have my button connected to the "Touch Cancel" method in storyboard, is there anything I can do to make this work? Also, I have a "Touch Down" method for the timer to start:

```
- (IBAction)begin:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Comment: You want the "touch up inside" event for the button.

Comment: The begin or stop button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a UIButton fire off an IBAction when it is pressed and released you will want to use the "Touch Up Inside" sent event and not "Touch Cancel".

Comment: Using "touch up inside" is used when you want the action to fire when the button is released, not pressed. You use "touch down" to fire the action when the button is first touched.

Comment: @Maddy, what you say is true, but for buttons you almost always want the action to trigger on touch up. That's the norm. To the OP, what's your goal? Do you want one action to trigger and then a second (stop) action to trigger on touch up?

Comment: @DuncanC I understand and agree. My comment was because the answer is sort of confusing by saying that "touch up inside" is used when the button is "pressed".

Comment: @DuncanC I wanted a timer to run while the button was being held down and it to stop when the finger was removed. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: MRR, then you want 2 separate actions, one on touch down inside, and a second one on touch up inside (and probably also on touch up outside)